# Pattern match function in Scheme Meta Circular Evaluator

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket, metacircular

I'm trying to add a **pattern matching function** to an existing scheme meta circular evaluator (this is homework) and I'm a bit lost on the wording of the instructions. I was hoping someone more skilled in this regard could help me interpret this.

The syntax for match should look like the following: `(match a ((p1 v1) (p2 v2) (p3 v3)))`

And it could be used to find length like so:

```
(define length (lambda (x)
   (match x (('() 0)
             (('cons a b) (+ 1 (length b))))))
```

The pattern language in the function should contain numeric constants, quoted constants, variables, and cons. If patterns are exhausted without finding a match, an error should be thrown.

I thought I understood the concept of pattern matching but implementing it in a function this way has me a bit thrown off. Would anyone be willing to explain what the above syntax is doing (specifically, how match is used in length above) so I can get a better understanding of what this function should do?

Comment: Is this actually supposed to be a function, or a macro/source transformation?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the chapter four, [Structured Types and the Semantics of Pattern Matching](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/slpj-book-1987/PAGES/051.HTM), from *The Implementation of Functional Languages*. The chapter is written by Simon L. Peyton Jones and Philip Wadler.

Comment: The chapter shows the rewrite rules needed to implement a pattern matcher.

Answer (score 1):

```
(match x (('() 0)
          (('cons a b) (+ 1 (length b)))))
```

It may be most helpful to consider what this code would need to *expand* into.  For each pattern, you'd need a test to determine whether the object you're trying to match *matches*, and you'd need code to figure out how to bind variables to its subparts.  In this case, you'd want an expansion roughly like:

```
(if (equal? '() x)
    0
    (if (pair? x)
        (let ((a (car x))
              (b (cdr x)))
          (+ 1 (length b)))
        ;; indicate failure to match
        'NO-MATCH))
```

You could write that with a **cond**, too, of course, but if you have to procedurally expand this, it might be easier to use nested **if** forms.

If you're actually implementing this as a function (and not as a macro (i.e., source transformation), then you'll need to specify exactly how you can work with environments, etc.